# What's the best way to ensure no null values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This question may be more about opinion than fact, but I'm unsure so thought I'd ask.

I'm building some forms which will display data and allow edits, the field data comes from props (as a parent component is using a GraphQL query to pull a larger amount and pass to each child).

I'm finding some input data is evaluating to null (as it's not passed back from the query) which throws a warning as inputs don't like being assigned null values.

My question is, when passing these values, what's the cleanest way to run checks on each variable and assign an empty string if needed?

So far the two options i've tried are:

Conditionally assign each to the state object, but this feels clunky and is a lot of code:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    telephone: props.telephone ? props.telephone : '',
    nickname: props.nickname ? props.nickname : ''
    etc...
});
```

Or to define a function which maps over props and checks values, before setting state:

```
useEffect( () => {
    let state_arr = {};
    Object.keys(props).map( (key) => {
        if( !props[key] ) state_arr[key] = '';
        else state_arr[key] = props[key];
    } );
    setState(state_arr);
}, [] )
```

Honestly this feels cleaner than the first option, but there are a number of places this will occur and to have to do this in each feels counter productive.

Any help/insight appreciated.

Comment: What is this state used for? It *looks* you're deriving values from props rather than  needing to use state here. If that's the case, I would skip the useEffect hook and use `||` whenever I was accessing a potentially null value.

Comment: It's used when editing values:
`function onInputChange( e ) {
  setState({ ...state, [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
 }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** It turns out OP is using Material UI for this..Meaning, the reason the input is showing a warning is due to Material UI using PropTypes. I suggested that OP create a wrapper for the `<Input />` component and pass through all props. Inside of the wrapper component you can just do: `<InputWrapper value={props.value || ""} {...rest} />` and this covers things..

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cj79hk?embed=1&file=index.js)

**InputWrapper:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Input } from '@material-ui/core';

export default function InputWrapper({ value, ...rest }) {
  return <Input value={value || ""} {...rest} />
}
```

**InputWrapper In Use:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import InputWrapper from './InputWrapper.js';


function App(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setState({
      name: props.name,
      age: props.age,
      hairColor: props.hairColor,
    })
  }, [props.name, props.age, props.hairColor]);

  const handleChange = (event, inputType) => {
    setState({...state, [inputType]: event.target.value})
  }

  return(
    <div>
      {/* Shows that you can pass through native <Input /> props: */}
      {/* state.name is null here! Warning is NOT thrown in the console! */}
      <InputWrapper value={state.name} fullWidth onChange={e => setState({...state, name: e.target.value})} />
      <InputWrapper value={state.name} multiline onChange={e => setState({...state, name: e.target.value})} />

      {Object.keys(state).map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <InputWrapper 
              key={`${item}_${index}`} 
              value={state[item]} 
              onChange={e => handleChange(e, item)} />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

render(
  <App name={null} age={44} hairColor="blue" />, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

---

***ORIGINAL ANSWER:***

What is your use case? There is no reason to run checks and assign empty strings...

If you are trying to enforce that certain properties are used, please look into [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes)... If you are not wanting to enforce that certain props get used, I would recommend checking for a value during use of the variable. Even if you set it to an empty string initially, you could still encounter errors down the line - I don't understand what you gain from an empty string.

I don't understand the use case - can you elaborate more on *why* you need to set it to an empty string?

If you really wanted to, you could verify like: `useState({two: props.two || ""})` ...but it is still unnecessary..

```js
// Notice how prop "two" is not being used..

function Test(props) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    one: props.one,
    two: props.two
  })
  
  return(
    <div>
      <p>{state.one}</p>
      <p>Even though <code>state.two</code> does not exist, there are no errors.. (at least for this demonstration)</p>
      <input type="text" value={state.two} />
      <input type="text" value={state.two} defaultValue={"default"} />
      <p><i>If you really wanted to, you could verify like:</i><code>useState(&#123;two: props.two || ""&#125;)</code><i>...but it is still unnecessary..</i></p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test one="I AM ONE" />, document.body)
```

```css
code {
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 3px;
  color: red;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Assigning null values to inputs throws the warning ``value` prop on `input` should not be null` - I'm running these checks to resolve this

Comment: And yes, assigning each piece of state as `useState({two: props.two || ""})` is an option, but with forms that hold 15-20 inputs it's not exactly clean

Comment: There we go, now we are getting somewhere!  You are passing the props to `input` fields.. In my opinion, the best way to handle this is by using [PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes) to require those props be used... ***orrrrr*** have you tried using the `defaultValue={""}` prop on the inputs?  Furthermore, I do not get any warning or error when supplying a null variable in `value`... I have updated answer to reflect this...(no errors or warning in console)...

Comment: @MattOestreich while it's a good idea to recommend prop types, they will not solve the problem OP has (some values being null) - it'll just warn him at runtime that they are null, which he already knows

Comment: @DanPantry OP must not be using built in HTML `<input/>` tags then.. It actually sounds like whichever package OP is using for design, is actually using `PropTypes` itself (throwing a warning because 'they' specified `value` as a required prop)... I cannot reproduce a warning or an error using built in `<input/>` tags..  Furthermore, `PropTypes` was not my only recommendation...

Comment: My point is that if you use PropTypes to 'enforce' something is not null, all you will get is a warning that something is null. It will have no impact at runtime. You should get a warning if you do `<input value={null} />` even with native HTML elements. Finally, `defaultValue` is only useful for uncontrolled components - if you're specifying `value={}` (like OP is), `defaultValue` should be replaced with `value={foo || default}`, as in your answer :)


To be clear I am responding to your comments rather than your original answer

Comment: Fair enough as far as PropTypes are concerned.. As far as `defaultValue` is concerned, my example above does NOT behave as you say.  I am technically supplying `value={} defaultValue={"default"}` and it is working as expected.  My point was, if OP manually puts `defaultValue={""}` on each `input` then there is no need to run checks. Cheers!

Comment: I'm using Material-UI for inputs. I originally thought it was likely to be the library but when googling I found other examples which weren't related to the same library. As I mentioned, using `value={foo || default}` was an option I'd considered but when there are 10+ values in state it felt like a better option could be available

Comment: @AdamRoberts I am still unable to reproduce this error... https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cj79hk?embed=1&file=index.js

Comment: @MattOestreich The variables you set in state are `undefined` - mine are specifically `null` as they are returned from GraphQL. Change `name` to `null` and you'll see the error - I just reproduced it within your example

Comment: @AdamRoberts ok that makes sense...Your best bet is to create a wrapper for the built-in `Input` component from Material UI and use `value={value || ""}`.  You can pass through all props, and use it as if it were the native `<Input />` component from Material UI.. [Please see the updated code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cj79hk?embed=1&file=InputWrapper.js)

Comment: I've built so many wrappers for other components while working on this project, I can't BELIEVE I didn't think of doing something so simple! Thanks dude, working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

What about making method KickOutNullValues() which will do what you want and then you can reuse it everywhere you need. That would be more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough question, i don't know the right answer. You already tried two ways, the different way that I normally do is,

If you just want to get the display right, i would just do

```
   <Telephone data={props.telephone} />,
   const Telephone = ({data}) => { if (!data) return null }
```

I found this is to allow the child component to ensure the validity of this issue rather than sorting out the data in the parent API level.

```
   Telephone.defaultProps = {
     data: ''
   }
```

This further ensures that if the data is null, it'll be reset to '' by the `defaultProps`

The reason I prefer this way most of time is that I don't really want to mess with the origin TRUTH of the API data.

Of course your ways might be better if you do want to ensure the data is valid at all time :)

Comment: Wouldn't this approach involve creating a constant for each input? I like the idea but to do this in a form with 20 inputs may be a nightmare

Comment: That's true, if you need to ensure this object exists from the very beginning, then yes. You are right, ex. via `redux`. I only tried to solve the problem from the display perspective. And I don't normally care if the object reference changes or not most of time via `React.Memo`

Comment: The thing i want to add as well is that if you change something from `null` to something, ex. `onChange`.  you would always end up with a new object. So from that perspective, maybe your way is the only way :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will start to have spaghetti-like qualities if you put the raw algorithm inside your callback. I recommend writing a `function` outside.

Your usage of `Array#map` is not correct, or rather you are using it in an unintended way. `Array#map` is used to construct an entirely new array. You are simulating `Array#forEach`. Also, you're performing a falsey conditional check. `null` is one of many values that are considered `false` in JavaScript. Namely, your pain points will probably be `undefined`, `0`, and `''`. If the only invalid return value is `null`, then check for `null` explicitly.

The enumerable that is for your intended use case is `Array#reduce`:

```
function nullValueReplacer(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((newStateArr, [currentKey, currentValue]) => {
    if (currentValue === null) {
      newStateArr[currentKey] = ''
    } else {
      newStateArr[currentKey] = currentValue
    }
    return newStateArr
  }, {});
}
```

As a side note, you might want to update your variable names. It's pretty deceptive that you have a variable called `state_arr` that is an object.

Comment: Sorry if I've misunderstood - but as I'm iterating over props, which is immutable, wouldn't constructing a new array be the intended behaviour?

Comment: @AdamRoberts `Array#reduce` creates a new entity. You are not mutating props when you use it. The algorithm I have is functionally identical to what you have in you have in your 2nd code block

Comment: I understand `reduce` creates a new entity, but what is the benefit in using `reduce` over `map`. As in both cases I need to create a new array and assign it to state

Comment: @AdamRoberts The benefit is the fact that humans need to read the code. When you use functions in ways they were not designed to, you will confuse yourself and others. At the end of the day, [essentially] all enumerables iterate over the array and you can use any one you want. When do you use `Array#map`? When you want to directly build a new array with modified values in one operation. `Array#filter`, when you want to selectively remove elements. You can use `filter` instead of `map` and your code will still work. But should you?

Comment: So we use reduce because the resulting object is the single output value?

Comment: @AdamRoberts `reduce` is a very versatile enumberable whose use case overlaps with an overwhelming majority of other array enumerables. But yes, `reduce` is the only one that can return a non-array value

Answer (score 0):

### Array of objects - little fix

You should not use key with map..

think about this: (similar to yours)

```
useEffect(() => {
  let state_arr = Object.keys(props).map(prop =>  prop ? {prop} : { prop: '' });
  setState(state_arr);
}, [])
```

By using this code you make an array with object and have easy access for every item

In case there is no nickname it will look like that:

`[{ telephone: '245-4225-288' }, { nickname: '' }]`

What do you think?